# How to add space between bootstrap buttons in same div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons inside same div i want to add space between these buttons. How can i achieve that without adding custom css. Is there any bootstrap solution for it ?

main.html

```
 <div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">View/Edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Ratings</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use CSS? This is exactly what it is design for. And no, bootstrap can't help you.

Comment: use `margin-right: 10px` or whatever fits you

Comment: One simple solution is, remove btn-group. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/122/

Comment: I have to agree with @Turnip. Why avoid CSS when ut is exactly the tool designed for what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend linking a css file and tampering with div margin isolated to the designated class.

IE)

```
<div class="Name1">
    <button class="Name2" type="button">View/Edit</button>
    <button class="Name3" type="button">Edit Ratings</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.name2 button
{
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

Otherwise,

An HTML alternative would be...

```
&nbsp;
```

Comment: It would be margin-right:5px; but the concept is there.

Comment: Classes suffixed with `1` and `2`? Really? How about `:first/last-child`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a rudimentary solution using bootstrap only. You could play around with the `col-md-*` to achieve desired gap.

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right row">
  <div class="col-md-4"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">View/Edit</button></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Edit Ratings</button></div>
 </div>
```