# How to add space between right align bootstrap button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to add 3 spaces between two right align button. Is there any bootstrap solution for it without adding custom css?

[image]

I do this :

```
    <div class="text-right">
           <button class="btn-info btn">Log in</button>
<!-- Add 3 spaces between button -->
           <button class="btn-info btn">Log Out </button>
    </div>
```

Fiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/6816gq84/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this rudimentary solution: [How to add space between bootstrap buttons in same div?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32957278/710955).

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right row">
   <div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Clôturer</button></div>
   <div class="col-md-1"></div>
   <div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Soumettre</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Voting it down as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015022/how-to-add-space-between-right-align-bootstrap-button#answer-36015256 is a much better solution by @SASM

Answer (score 21):

You can add `btn-toolbar` class to the container `div`.

```
<div class="text-right btn-toolbar">
       <button class="btn-info btn">Log in</button>
       <button class="btn-info btn">Log Out </button>
</div>
```

Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6816gq84/3/).

Comment: It only worked with `pull-right` instead of `text-right` for me

Comment: Nice. :). It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This also work fine for me:

```
<div style="display: flex ; justify-content: flex-end">
    <button class="btn-info btn mr-3">Log in</button>
    <button class="btn-info btn">Log Out </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure any bootstrap solution already exists for what you want to do, but there are other way, depending what you mean by "custom css".

You can add a span balise for exemple and add an inline css defining the width to 3em (3 spaces). It's HTML/CSS but you don't modify the css of the button's class.

```
<div class="text-right">
       <button class="btn-info btn">Log in</button>
       <span style="width:3em;"> </span>
       <button class="btn-info btn">Log Out </button>
</div>
```